# Exclude a tag (<pattern>) inside a tag (<topic>) on a result set using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags, aiml

I'm just new to web scraping using Python, and currently I'm using BeautifulSoup for data extraction. I have this .aiml file(xml) wherein I wanted to extract all the data from the tags **pattern** which are **NOT INCLUDED**  inside the **topic** tag.

I'm already getting all the pattern values, but the challenge here is that, those pattern that has a parent tag of **topic**, shouldn't be included on a result set.

Here is the aiml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<aiml version="1.0.1" encoding="UTF-8">
  <topic name="botdog">
   <category>
      <pattern>MY DOG'S NAME IS *</pattern>
      <template>
         That is interesting that you have a dog named <set name="dog"><star/></set>
      </template>  
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>WHAT IS MY DOG'S NAME</pattern>
      <template>
         Your dog's name is <get name="dog"/>.
      </template>  
   </category>  
  </topic>

  <topic name="botcat">
   <category>
      <pattern>MY CAT'S NAME IS *</pattern>
      <template>
         That is interesting that you have a cat named <set name="cat"><star/></set>
      </template>  
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>WHAT IS MY CAT'S NAME</pattern>
      <template>
         Your cat's name is <get name="cat"/>.
      </template>  
   </category>  
  </topic>


  <category>
      <pattern>HELLO ALICE</pattern>
      <template>
         Hello User
      </template>
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>HOW ARE YOU</pattern>
      <template>
         I'm fine
      </template>
   </category>
</aiml>
```

Python code(Flask):

```
@extract.route('/')
def index_page():
    folder = 'templates/topic.aiml'
    with open(folder, 'r') as myfile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile.read(), 'html.parser')
    data_topic = [match.pattern.text for match in soup.find_all('category')]

    print(data_topic)


    # data = " ".join(data_set)

    return jsonify({'data_set': data_topic})
```

Return value upon print() is:

**["MY DOG'S NAME IS *", "WHAT IS MY DOG'S NAME", "MY CAT'S NAME IS *", "WHAT IS MY CAT'S NAME", 'HELLO ALICE', 'HOW ARE YOU']**

Which should only be like this since it has no parent tag **topic**:
**['HELLO ALICE', 'HOW ARE YOU']**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@extract.route('/')
def index_page():
    folder = 'templates/topic.aiml'

    with open(folder, 'r') as myfile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile.read(), 'html.parser')

    data = []
    for cat in soup.find_all('category'):
        if cat.parent.name == "topic": continue
        data += [cat.find("pattern").text]

    print(data)
    return jsonify({'data_set': data})
```

Hope this helps! Check out the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more examples.

Comment: That was **great**! Thanks man! :) Before I saw your answer, what I did was: **for x in soup.find_all('topic'): x.extract() **, of course it's inappropriate since I'm already removing the tags. But when I use your code and print the soup, it was still there, and I got the expected result set. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help, go and *print more soup* :)